# Tell Interviewer About On Leave Plan

Tags: interviewing

I plan to have leave around July about 1 week and will be in probation period if I move to another job.

Should I tell the interviewer that I will have 1 week leave on July during job interview?

Comment: Yes you should, honesty is almost always the best policy.

Answer (score 2):

I have always had good luck with being upfront about a planned vacation.  I would mention it during the interview and again when you receive a job offer.  Always say that you are intending to take the time without pay since you usually don't have any vacation time yet.  Best case scenario they let you take vacation time before it is earned and worst case you take it unpaid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that 'tell' and 'will' are the correct words to use in this situation.
You should *ask* the interviewer if it would be *acceptable* for you to take a week of leave during your probation period, and then be prepared to walk away from the job if they say no.

Not mentioning it at all is likely to cause heartache for you in one of 2 ways if they disallow it (which I think is likely as most companies would look poorly on the idea of taking leave during your probation period) - either you will be upset that you can't take your planned leave, or you will be upset that they fire you for taking unapproved leave...